# How to display a specific region?

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm using the plugin `jvectormap` with `Italy` country, I followed the documentation, and I actually declared the map as following:

```
$('#worldMap').vectorMap({map: 'it_regions_mill'});
```

so I get this result:

[image]

How can I display a specific region of `Italy`? eg: Milan?

Comment: Lots of research available to you if you search here and on the web. What research have you tried? Are you actually using the `regions` as described in all the FAQs? Make sure you exhaust all the resources available to you so others don't redo all the same research.